# Проблемы с версткой под opencart

Tags: php, html, вёрстка, opencart

Здравствуйте. Работаю со свежей версией opencart. Задача простая - сверстать свой дизайн, столкнулся со следующей проблемой: при изменении файла .twig (например header.twig) на самом сайте ничего не меняется. Методом тыка определил, что после изменений в файле необходимо зайти в "редактор шаблона", открыть там редактируемый файл, сохранить и только тогда что-то меняется на сайте. Как Вы понимаете, процесс время- и нервнозатратный. Видимо, есть что-то, что пишет изменения в бд, и оттуда уже потом загружает сайт. Я не знаю. Кто-нибудь сталкивался? Знаете решения или может отключить этот функционал можно как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения этой проблемы необходимо отключить кеширование файлов шаблона (.twig). 
[Линк с подробной инструкцией](https://opencart3x.ru/blog/clear-cache)

Comment: Нерабочее решение